# 301 redirect a single page results in wrong link address

Tags: html, redirect

I want to redirect [https://tolelight.com.vn/chi-tiet/15/tam-lop-lay-sang-tolelight®.html](https://tolelight.com.vn/chi-tiet/15/tam-lop-lay-sang-tolelight%C2%AE.html) to https://tolelight.com.vn/chi-tiet/15/tam-lop-lay-sang.html, my code is:

```
Redirect 301 /chi-tiet/15/tam-lop-lay-sang-tolelight®.html https://tolelight.com.vn/chi-tiet/15/tam-lop-lay-sang.html
```

.htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)(.+) [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.+)
RewriteRule ^ https://%2%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
#danh-muc
#RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*).html$ index.php?page=$1&catid=$2&id=$3&link=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*).html$ index.php?page=$1&catid=$2&id=$3&link=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*).html$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2&link=$3 [L]
# lam moi tin  & xac nhan ma code quen mat khau
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ index.php?page=$1&confirm_code=$2&id=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [L]

#RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
#RewriteRule ^([\w]+).html index.php?page=$1 [L]
# phan trang news
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)$ index.php?page=$1&start=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)$ index.php?page=$1&catid=$2&start=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)$ index.php?page=$1&catid=$2&key=$3&start=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)$ index.php?page=$1&catid=$2&congsuat=$3&luuluong=$4&start=$5 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)$ index.php?page=$1&catid=$2&congsuat=$3&luuluong=$4&cotap=$5&start=$6 [L]
# Permanent URL redirect - generated by www.rapidtables.com
Redirect 301 /chi-tiet/15/tam-lop-lay-sang-tolelight®.html https://tolelight.com.vn/chi-tiet/15/tam-lop-lay-sang.html
# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on

    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on

    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
 </IfModule>
```

But the result is this:
https://tolelight.com.vn/chi-tiet/15/tam-lop-lay-sang.html?page=chi-tiet&id=15&link=tam-lop-lay-sang-tolelight%C2%AE

Answer (score 0):

This is because of comment after `https://`.

So Try to use backslashes(`\`) like

```
https:\\tolelight.com.vn/chi-tiet/15/tam-lop-lay-sang.html
```

instead of

```
Redirect 301 /chi-tiet/15/tam-lop-lay-sang-tolelight®.html https://tolelight.com.vn/chi-tiet/15/tam-lop-lay-sang.html
```

Use this:

```
Redirect 301 /chi-tiet/15/tam-lop-lay-sang-tolelight®.html https:\\tolelight.com.vn/chi-tiet/15/tam-lop-lay-sang.html
```

This might help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it does not work, still results in the unwanted link.